# Retrieving single direct message and waiting for people to message using Tweepy

Tags: api, twitter, message, tweepy, rate

Am having a problem here where I get Twitter rate limit so quickly and I don't get the new DMs quick

This is the code please help me.

```
def getDM():

           last_seen_id = retrieve_last_seen_id(FILE_NAME)
           last_dms = api.list_direct_messages(1)

           for messages in last_dms:
               last_seen_id = messages.id #messages.message_create['sender_id']
               store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, FILE_NAME)
               print("ID is : " + str(messages.id) + " || " + " Messaged : " + 
               str(messages.message_create['message_data']['text']))
               api.destroy_direct_message(messages.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to implement a thread which fetches the DMs every 60 seconds, if you try more often you do exceed the limit

```
class TwitterThread():
   def start(self):
      self.interval = 60  # interval

      thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
      thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize thread
      logging.info(f'TwitterThread runs every {self.interval} seconds')
      thread.start()

   def run(self):
      while True:
         try:
            last_dms = api.list_direct_messages(1)
            for messages in last_dms:
               # process DM

               api.destroy_direct_message(messages.id)

         except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)

        time.sleep(self.interval)  # sleep to wait 60 sec
```